# Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `x' or `x@' (in 'x^2-3x')

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x^2-3x} node {$y=x^2-3x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

error message is: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `x' or` x@' (in 'x^2-3x').

Comment: You need to write the multiplication operator explicitly (`3*x`). Also the `node` should not be there, so `\addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x^2-3*x};% no node here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Have a look to my proposal:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick=\empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [domain=-4:5] {x^2 - 3*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the nodes, and how should I make  the nodes visible?